# $AB$ is diameter of a semicircle and $S$ is incircle of $ABC$. Find $\angle ASB$.

Tags: geometry

$AB$ is the diameter of a semicircle. $C$ is an  arbitrary point on the semicircle and $S$ is the centre of circle inscribed in the triangle $ABC$. What is the measure of the angle $\angle ASB$?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the triangle is a right triangle with ∠A + ∠B = 90. Also, since S is the incenter,  SA and SB are the angle bisectors of ∠A and ∠B, respectively.

Thus,

$$\angle ASB = 180 - \frac{\angle A + \angle B}{2} = 180 - \frac{90}{2}=135  $$

Comment: How SA and SB are angle bisectors Of  ∠A and ∠B

Comment: @RaghavDixit - Because S is the center of the inscribed circle inside the triangle ABC. You could also prove by drawing the heights from S to the two sides and look for two congruent triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Here a picture that maybe can be useful[image].